# Create Stored procedure dynamically by Java in MS SQL server 2012

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to create Stored procedure dynamically,from my code of Java.I searched for any kind of example but can't find anything.In the internet I found a lot of examples of how to run stored procedure,but I need to create it from my code.What I tried to do is :

```
    StringBuilder strbuild=new StringBuilder();
    strbuild.append("USE [ARGOS] \n");
    strbuild.append("GO\n");
    strbuild.append("SET ANSI_NULLS ON\n");
    strbuild.append("GO\n");
    strbuild.append("SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON\n");
    strbuild.append("GO\n");
    strbuild.append("CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sptest10] \n");
    strbuild.append("as select *\n");       
    strbuild.append("FROM [ARGOSCOPE].[dbo].[TableTmp2] \n");   
    strbuild.append("GO\n");



    Statement stmt = myconnection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(strbuild.toString());
```

But it doesn't work.Any suggestions?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The Oracle Java tutorials for JDBC has an example that deals with this exact thing: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html#create_jdbc_mysql

Comment: You are not building a query, so `executeQuery` will fail.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
 at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
 at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
 at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
 at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
 at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:505)
 at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeQuery(JtdsStatement.java:1427)
 at w_old.test.JDBClayer.readDB(JDBClayer.java:172)

Comment: Why do you need to create a stored procedure from code like this? And why are you selecting *?

Comment: GO is NOT a sql statement. It is the batch separator in SSMS.

Comment: @GáborBakos what I need to use?

Answer (score 2):

`GO` is not something you can specify here in this piece of SQL/T-SQL code.
It only applies to SQL Server Management Studio and other specific tools.
Just don't use `GO` statements here.

See also:

[GO - SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)

> > GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.

Answer (score 1):

The GO statement is used in SQL Server Management Studio to allow you to string together what would normally be a series of independently executed statements. This is to allow you to execute scripts containing multiple commands that must be the first statement in a query, such as CREATE PROCEDURE.

If you split your statement into multiple string on the string "\nGO\n" and execute them in sequence using the same connection, you will reproduce the behavior of clicking Execute in SSMS.